# how to roll a die until 20 rolls 3 or lower are rolled Python

Tags: python

I've been trying to write it so it pulls from

```
roll_dice = random.randint(1,6)
```

but its only been set to one number so it's always equal to the same number. here's the full code:

```
import random

roll_dice = random.randint(1,6)

rolls = 0
check = 0
while check <= 20:
    roll_dice
    if roll_dice < 4:
        check = check +  1
        rolls =  rolls + 1
    elif roll_dice > 0:
        rolls += rolls + 1
    elif check == 20:
        print("it took", rolls, "to reach 20 rolls under 3")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `roll_dice = random.randint(1, 6)` inside the while loop so that each iteration the value of `roll_dice` changes, and is a random number from 1 to 6.

I.e, without changing the structure of your code too much,

```py
import random
rolls = 0
check = 0
while check <= 20:
    rolls =  rolls + 1 #add 1 to rolls counter
    roll_dice = random.randint(1,6) #Set roll_dice to random int from 1-6
    if roll_dice < 4: #if it is 3 or lower, add 1 to check
        check = check +  1
    if check == 20: #if 20 rolls of 3 or less, then print and stop loop
        print("it took", rolls, "rolls to reach 20 rolls under 3")
        break
```

**Sample Output:**

```
it took 32 rolls to reach 20 rolls under 3
```